# FormsAuthentication and IsValid method does not exist in current context error

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

i'm new with ASP.net web app and i'm currently creating login validation form by taking data from specific database. I'm using FormsAuthentication model to bound directory during log in process. But instead i received red-line on the model, as follows:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGUY6.png)

login.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RedoAssignment.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RedoAssignment.Table;
using System.Web;

namespace RedoAssignment.Pages
{
public class loginModel : PageModel
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult login()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult login(Models.RedoAssignmentContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.email, User.password);
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
             }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

User.cs model

```
 public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int customerID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string fullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string contactNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know where do i make mistakes, thank you.

Edit:
I used to add **if(User.IsValid(User.email, User.password))** value before, but there was red line on **IsValid**statement.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          if(User.IsValid(User.email, User.password))
           {
           FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.email, User.password);
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() does not accept two string arguments as 
   parameters.
2. `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(string email, bool createPersistentCookie);`
3. Never set your password in a cookie
4. You cannot use any of the User model properties since it is not instantiated and it is 
   not a static class. //User.email
5. User.IsValid() will not work since there is no such method in your User class.
6. Better use .net Identity or any other preferred way to validate the user.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
 if(condition) //validate whether user exists
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true/false);
 else
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
}
```